# get pixel alpha value

Tags: gimp, alpha-channel

Given a pixel in an image imported from a png file, how can I get the alpha value of the pixel with the GIMP? If this is not possible, what software can I use to achieve this (OS: Linux)?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Hold shift while using the color picker.